# Plotting a recursive relation

Tags: plotting

I would like to make a plot of $x_{n}$ against $n$ for the following recursive relation:

$$x_{n} = \frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\cosh(2x_{n-1})\right)$$

I would like to plot graphs for arbitrary values of $x_{0}$.

How do I write the code in Mathematica?

Comment: What about using a [Cobweb Plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot), instead?

Answer (score 7):

You can also define the recursion directly:

```
Clear[x]; 
x[n_] := x[n] = (1/2) Log[Cosh[2 x[n - 1]]];
```

Then:

```
x[0] = 25.; ListPlot[x[#] & /@ Range[100]]
```

Comment: To avoid potential problems recommend that you always use the form: `x[n_Integer?Positive] := x[n] = ...`

Answer (score 7):

@rcollyers version with Cobweb List:

```
cobwebList := Partition[Sequence @@ {#, #} & /@ pts, 2, 1]

f[x_] = (1/2) Log[Cosh[2 x]];
startPoint = 1.0;
pts = RecurrenceTable[{x[n] == 1/2 Log[Cosh[2*x[n - 1]]], x[1] == startPoint}, x, {n, 1, 5}]
```

{1., 0.662501, 0.350061, 0.113672, 0.0128115}

With the friendly suggestion of @rcollyer (slightly modified)

```
nticks = MapIndexed[{#1, "n" <> ToString[First@#2]} &, pts];
Show[
 Plot[{x, f[x]}, {x, Last@pts, startPoint}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Dashed],
  GridLines -> {pts, pts}, Ticks -> {nticks, SetAccuracy[pts, 4]}],
 Graphics[{Red, Arrow@Partition[cobwebList, 2, 1]}]
 ]
```

[image]

For another arbitrary start point:

```
startPoint = 25.0;
pts = RecurrenceTable[{x[n] == 1/2 Log[Cosh[2*x[n - 1]]], x[1] == startPoint}, x, {n, 1, 70}];

nticks = MapIndexed[{#1, "n" <> ToString[First@#2]} &, pts];
Show[Plot[{x, f[x]}, {x, pts[[6]], startPoint}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Dashed], GridLines -> {pts, pts}, 
  Ticks -> {nticks, SetAccuracy[pts, 4]}], 
 Graphics[{Red, Arrow@Partition[cobwebList, 2, 1]}]]
```

[image]

or choose another range:

```
nticks = MapIndexed[{#1, "n" <> ToString[First@#2]} &, pts];
Show[Plot[{x, f[x]}, {x, Last@pts, pts[[65]]}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Dashed], GridLines -> {pts, pts}, 
  Ticks -> {nticks, SetAccuracy[pts, 4]}], 
 Graphics[{Red, Arrow@Partition[cobwebList, 2, 1]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Love that `cobwebList`!

Comment: This is a great start (+1), but I would do things a little differently. :) First, I'd make them a common color, `color = ColorData[97][1]`, and differentiate the lines on `Plot` by setting `PlotStyle -> Directive[color, Dotted]`. Second, I would create the lines for the cobweb directly, but use `Arrow` instead via `Graphics[{color, Arrow@Partition[cobwebList, 2, 1]}]`. And, if you want to get creative, add `ticks = MapIndexed[{#1, "x[" <> ToString[#2[[1]]] <> "]"} &, pts]` via `Ticks -> {ticks, ticks}`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `RecurrenceTable`

```
sol1[x0_] := RecurrenceTable[{x[n] == 1/2 Log[Cosh[2*x[n - 1]]], 
        x[1] == x0}, {x}, {n, 1, 5}];
Show[ListLinePlot[Transpose@sol1[0.3], PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListLinePlot[Transpose@sol1[0.1], PlotStyle -> {Green},  PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Please read about [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) and [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html).

```
next[x_] := (1/2) Log[Cosh[2 x]]

result = NestList[next, (* x0 = *) 0.5, 20]

ListPlot[result, PlotRange -> All]
```

Since the starting value was `0.5`, i.e. inexact, the result is also inexact, and it is computed quickly.  If you use an exact starting value, e.g. `1` instead of `1.0`, then the result will be exact, and slow to compute.

See also:

- https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/27-applying-functions-repeatedly.html

Comment: I think the `x-1` should be `x`

Comment: @yode Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 6):

I would use `FixedPointList` for this computational task.

```
f[x_] := 1/2 Log[Cosh[2 x]]
xn[x0_] :=
  FixedPointList[
    Module[{n, x}, 
      {n, x} = #; {n + 1, N @ f[x]}] &, {1, x0}, 
      SameTest -> (Abs[Last[#1] - Last[#2]] < 1*^-3 &)]
```

Then

```
With[{x0max = 5},
  ListPlot[Table[xn[x0], {x0, x0max}],
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large],
    PlotLegends ->
      PointLegend[Range[x0max],
        LegendMarkers -> Graphics[Disk[]],
        LegendMarkerSize -> 16]]]
```

gives

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

Just combining a few elements from other answers:

```
f[x_] := Log[Cosh[2 x]]/2
nf[x0_, n_] := 
 Catenate[{{#1, #2}, {#2, #2}} & @@@ 
   NestList[{#[[2]], f[#[[2]]]} &, {x0, f@x0}, n]]
Manipulate[Animate[
  Row[{
    Show[
     Plot[{x, f[x]}, {x, -1, 1}],
     Graphics[{Red, ({{PointSize[0.02], Point[{x0, 0}]}, 
           Arrow[{{x0, 0}, {x0, f@x0}}]}~
          Join~(Arrow /@ Partition[nf[x0, 4], 2, 1]))[[1 ;; n]]}], 
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, ImageSize -> 300], 
    ListPlot[NestList[f, x0, 5][[1 ;; Ceiling[n/2]]], Joined -> True, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-1, 1}}, ImageSize -> 300, 
     PlotMarkers -> {Style[\[FilledDiamond], Red], 12}]}], {n, 1, 10, 
   1}, AnimationRunning -> False], {x0, -1, 1}]
```

[image]